# Retornar mais de uma variável em JQuery/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

Sendo objetivo, meu problema é o seguinte:

Tenho um formulário em PHP/HTML e estou usando um autopreenchimento de campos via Jquery. Este formulário trás os últimos números apostados pelo usuario e refaz a aposta com este números automaticamente sem ele precisar digitar tudo de novo.

Então tenho dois arquivos:

1) Formulário onde o usuario seleciona o sorteio que deseja repetir a aposta;

2) Página em .php que recebe a requisição do formulário de acordo com o sorteio escolhido pelo usuário, filtra e devolve os números daquele sorteio escolhido para o formulário.

No caso do arquivo 02, ao puxar com o arquivo isoladamente, ou seja, abrindo ele no navegador ele me retorna o valor correto dos números daquele usuário correspondendo ao sorteio escolhido, porém ao tentar selecionar o sorteio no arquivo 01 ele não puxa e preenche os dados... Aí que mora minha dúvida, o que pode estar acontecendo de errado?

Vamos aos códigos:

Arquivo 01:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function numeroConcurso(id){
                $.post("paginas/repetiraposta.php",{idConcurso:id},function(retorno){
                    dados = retorno.split("/");
                    $('#num01').val(dados[0]);
                    $('#num02').val(dados[1]);
                    $('#num03').val(dados[2]);
                    $('#num04').val(dados[3]);
                    $('#num05').val(dados[4]);
                    $('#num06').val(dados[5]);
                    $('#num07').val(dados[6]);
                    $('#num08').val(dados[7]);
                    $('#num09').val(dados[8]);
                    $('#num10').val(dados[9]);
                    $('#num11').val(dados[10]);
                    $('#num12').val(dados[11]);
                    $('#num13').val(dados[12]);
                    $('#num14').val(dados[13]);
                    $('#num15').val(dados[14]);
                    });
            }
    </script>

<!--FORMULÁRIO-->

<label>Repetir aposta do concurso:[EM DESENVOLVIMENTO]</label>
    <select name="concurso" onchange="numeroConcurso(this.value)">
        <option value="">Escolha um concurso</option>
            <?php 
                $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM numeros WHERE usuario='$usuario'");
                while($sorteio_atual = mysql_fetch_object($sql2)){
                echo "
                <option value='$sorteio_atual->sorteio'>
                        $sorteio_atual->sorteio</option>
                ";
                }
            ?>
    </select>
```

Arquivo 02:

```
$usuario1 = $_SESSION['usuario'];
$id = $_POST['idConcurso'];
$sqlConcurso = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM numeros WHERE usuario='$usuario1'");
$concurso = mysql_fetch_object($sqlConcurso);
$dados = $concurso->numero01."/".$concurso->numero02."/".$concurso->numero03."/".$concurso->numero04."/".$concurso->numero05."/".$concurso->numero06."/".$concurso->numero07."/".$concurso->numero08."/".$concurso->numero09."/".$concurso->numero10."/".$concurso->numero11."/".$concurso->numero12."/".$concurso->numero13."/".$concurso->numero14."/".$concurso->numero15."/".$concurso->usuario;
    echo $dados;
```

Então é isso:

Quero que o cara ao selecionar o sorteio, os números correspondentes ao código retornem no formulário automaticamente para ele refazer sua aposta!

Obs.:
Se eu alterar o arquivo 02 para:

```
$sqlConcurso = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM numeros WHERE usuario='$usuario1'");
```

O formulário 01 retorna os números de todos os jogadores sem filtrar pelo nome do usuário.

O controle do filtro está sendo realizado na função: `$_SESSION['usuario']`

Caso seja necessário, o exemplo do código está no site:

loteriamxt.tk

Guia "Apostar!".

Agradeço a todos pela atenção!

Ficou assim o código dentro do arquivo 02:

```
session_start(); 

$usuario1 = $_SESSION['usuario']; 

$id = $_POST['idConcurso']; $sqlConcurso = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM numeros WHERE sorteio='$id' AND usuario='$usuario1'");
```

Filtrando por usuario e por número de sorteio selecionado no formulário! Muito Obrigado Anderson Carlos Woss!

Comment: Antes de `dados = retorno.split("/");`, verifique via `console.log` o que está chegando para o JavaScript.

Comment: Como verifico isso?

Comment: `console.log(retorno)`, verifique a saída no console do navegador.

Comment: /////////////// 
Saíram apenas as barras que fazem a divisão dos números.

Era pra sair tipo: 01/02/03/04/05....

Comment: Se eu alterar o $sqlConcurso = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM numeros WHERE usuario='$usuario1'"); de acordo com a requisição do arquivo 01(idConcurso:id), ficando :$sqlConcurso = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM numeros WHERE sorteio='$id'");

O console me retorna: 07/13/15/23/25/33/45/12/08/17/35/37////francis1505

Mas estes números não são do meu usuário...

Comment: Você está chamando a função `session_start`?

Comment: Não diretamente no arquivo, mas em consulta dentro do arquivo com o echo $usuario1; onde $usuario1 = $_SESSION['usuario'];, ele me retorna o nome do meu usuário, ou do usuário que estiver logado no sistema.

Comment: Cara era o Session!!!

Ficou assim o código dentro do arquivo 02:

session_start();

$usuario1 = $_SESSION['usuario'];
$id = $_POST['idConcurso'];
$sqlConcurso = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM numeros WHERE sorteio='$id' AND usuario='$usuario1'");


Filtrando por usuario e por número de sorteio selecionado no formulário! Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Ficou assim o código dentro do arquivo 02:

```
session_start(); 

$usuario1 = $_SESSION['usuario']; 

$id = $_POST['idConcurso']; $sqlConcurso = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM numeros WHERE sorteio='$id' AND usuario='$usuario1'");
```

Filtrando por usuario e por número de sorteio selecionado no formulário! Muito Obrigado Anderson Carlos Woss!